# How to disambiguate clashing constructor names

Tags: agda

See for example [Data.Maybe.Base](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Maybe.Base.html) in the stdlib — all `Maybe`, `Any`, and `All` have a `just` constructor.

Agda allows these definitions. How can one specify which one to use?

Comment: Type inference. When you call one of the `just` functions, it will try to see what kind of result you need (based on where you use that result). If that remains ambiguous, you will get an error and have to add an explicit type declaration somewhere. Hopefully just one in a strategic location that makes all the rest clear (but explicit type declarations are always good style if only for documentation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each data type comes with its own module. So `Maybe`, `All` and `Any` are all type constructors and modules simultaneously. Thus you can write `Maybe.just`, `All.just` or `Any.just` to disambiguate the constructor. Or it can be disambiguated by type inference (unification is a more appropriate term) or an explicit type signature like [Thilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14955/thilo) said in their comment. (It's not true however that you'll get an error if there some ambiguity -- you'll get an unsolved meta).

Comment: If you want to get technical, the best term is probably something like "Type-directed disambiguation" which is possible when you're in type *checking* mode because you already have a type and, given that you want the expression to have that type, it's pretty clear which data type the constructor corresponds to.

Comment: @gallais, you can get that type by unification. I.e. if you have something like `let f = just in f (fromMaybe 0 (f 0))`, then both the `f`s will be disambiguated even though we can be in inference mode. But yes, the correct term for this sort of thing is type-directed name resolution.